# Rails first or initialize by one value, but add more values if created

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

Take the following for example:

`GroupMember.where(:member_id => 4).first_or_initialize`

What if I wanted to say something like this-

If GroupMember with a member_id of 4 exists, "find it". Otherwise, create a GroupMember with the member_id of 4 AND a group_id of 7.

So I want the above statement to only check for the member_id - But if it doesn't exist, I want it to create a GroupMember with multiple attributes. How would I write that? I am using rails 4.0.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

This is the reference I use - http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Relation/first_or_initialize

The method's source states:

```
def first_or_initialize(attributes = nil, &block)
  first || new(attributes, &block)
end
```

So, if the record is not found - it initialises a new one and passes to a block.

You can use it:

```
GroupMember.where(:member_id => 4).first_or_initialize do |member|
  member.group_id = 7
end
```

It will execute block for new record only.

Comment: Thank you so much. This will also allow me to initialize multiple other columns during initialization.

Answer (score 50):

This also works:

```
GroupMember.where(member_id: 4).first_or_initialize(group_id: 7)
```

The attributes passed to first_or_initialize are only used when it creates the new record, and they're merged with the attributes from the "where" clause.

Comment: It happens in ActiveRecord::Relation#new, which builds a nested scope -- the `where` clause parameters are in the outer scope and the `first_or_initialize` parameters go into the new scope, overriding the outer ones by the call to `scoping`. It's not terribly obvious, but it happens.

Answer (score 0):

Using

```
find_or_initialize_by_member_id_and_group_id(member_id, group_id)
```

you will create GroupMember uniq both by member_id and group id. (by is used only once)

I am not sure this statement will work on Rails 4 or not. It is working on Rails 3.2

Please check the above statement at rails console and let me know if it works on not.

**Update:**

As per the error console code has to be :

```
GroupMember.find_or_initialize_by(member_id: member_id, group_id: group_id )
```

Please verify the change works or not

Comment: Rails Console returns this:

`DEPRECATION WARNING: This dynamic method is deprecated. Please use e.g. Post.find_or_initialize_by(name: 'foo') instead. (called from irb_binding at (irb):17)`

Comment: The original version does technically work in Rails 4 (thus far), it merely also displays the deprecation warning luigi mentioned, and still returns the same data. @Luigi Consequently, you definitely want to use the second version Rubyist posted in order to avoid problems if/when the old `find_or_initialize_by...` version is removed entirely in future versions of Rails.

Answer (score 0):

try with this

```
Post.find_or_create_by(member_id: member_id, group_id: group_id )
```