# Rails find_or_create_by with/without where

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

Let's say I have a model named `Task`. And I want to `find_or_create_by` some task.

```
t = Task.where(done: false).find_or_create_by(title: 'epic')
```

This model works, but create a task with `title` equal to epic and `done` equal to false. I want query search through `done` equal to false, but I don't want new record `done` equal to false. How can I do it?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21190577/2697183. You can override the `done` value if a new instance is created

Comment: thanks for links, but they are use `first_or_create` which is outdated I think

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use something called: [`find_or_initialize_by`](http://apidock.com/rails/v4.0.2/ActiveRecord/Relation/find_or_initialize_by). It only initializes the record, but doesn't create it. This way, you can override the properties later on:

```
 task = Task.where(done: false).find_or_initialize_by(title: 'epic').first
 task.done = true # or nil or whatever you want!
 task.save
```

I only saved the first record with `task.done = true`. If there are more than one record, you can use `each` to iterate through all of them, and save them all.

**Edit:**

```
Task.where(:done => false).first_or_initialize do |task|
  task.done = true
  task.title = 'epic'
end
```