# Rails combine searching by enum and find_or_initialize_by methods

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, enums

*this question is based on this one: [Rails find_or_create_by with/without where](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30952981/rails-find-or-create-by-with-without-where)*

I've experienced some strange issue about `enum` & `find_or_initialize_by` methods in rails.

Let suppose I have the model `Task`.

```
class Task < AR::Base
  enum status: { todo: 0, awaiting: 1, done: 2, another_one: 3, et.c. }
```

I want to find through `todo` and `awaiting` tasks, and if there is no exist, create a new one, but without a `todo` and `awaiting` value (status should be just nil). But, `ActiveRecord::Enum` strikes here!

This is the normal code in most cases:

```
Task.where(status: [Task.statuses[:todo], Task.statuses[:awaiting]]).find_or_initialize_by(title: 'epic')
```

But because of [this](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/08576b94ad4f19dfc368619d7751e211d23dcad8/activerecord/lib/active_record/enum.rb#L105) string I get annoying `'[0, 1]' is not a valid status` exception. How can I avoid this exception without superfluous code?

Comment: What happens when you change it to like this `enum status: [:todo, :awaiting, :done]` ?

Comment: These lines are equal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For now I see just one relatively cool solution. Will be great if somebody another gives solution better.

1. Install `gem 'active_record_union'`
2. Use it!

   `Task.todo.union(Task.awaiting).union(Task.starting)`

Answer (score 0):

When querying an enum attribute you should use [the symbol representing the enum](http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Enum.html) and not the actual integer column value:

```
@task = Task.where(status: [:todo, :awaiting])
            .find_or_initialize_by(title: 'epic')
```

Hence the `'[0, 1]' is not a valid status` since Rails is trying to be helpful and look up the enum values for you. In general you almost never need to use the actual integer value unless your are building a custom SQL string:

```
Task.where.not(status: :awaiting)
```

Rails also generates scopes based on the enum:

```
@tasks = Task.todo.awaiting.find_or_initialize_by(title: 'epic')
# or
@tasks = Task.todo.merge(Task.awaiting)
             .find_or_initialize_by(title: 'epic')
```

Comment: This seems helpful, but it isn't. First solution because of there is a lot more statuses, second one with merges doesn't work.

Comment: Hmm, I didn't actually test merging the scopes so I was just assuming that Rails would join the two scopes together like it usually does with two `where` scopes.

Comment: Also what do you mean by " because of there is a lot more statuses"? There is is nothing preventing you from doing `status: [:todo, :awaiting, :happy, :sad...]`

Comment: So, I should write something like that: `Task.where.not(status: Task.statuses[:a_lot_of_another_statuses_here])`. It's easy to forgot add status here when I'll add another status to the model's enum

Comment: Please consider my answer, which works, but isn't ideal

Comment: No, you should use the symbol keys when querying with a hash! I also rejected your edit. Try re-reading my answer and the Rails Enum api documentation page, because you're obviously not getting it.

Comment: `Task.where.not(status: [:a_lot_of_another_statuses_here])`. And you don't need union queries.

Comment: But it's hardcorely simple to forgot about all queries of this type when you add new status to enum. But my solution isn't ideal too

Comment: I'm not totally sure what you are getting at - your question has a certain set of requirements and you're just inventing new ones as you go along. I have shown you how to query based on a enum status which is what your are asking. If you need to whitelist or blacklist statuses when creating that is entirely different question. I'm not spending more time on this one.

Comment: I've edited question 4 hrs ago. Anyway, thanks for trying to help!